# How to transform to pivot in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have queries like following one

```
select 
people
,week
,score
from table1
where people in ('a','b','c')
```

when I execute them, and finally , I get following result

```
people week score
a      1      1
a      1      2
b      2      2
c      3      3
c      4      4
```

But my goal and desired result is pivot by people and week, and the target is `sum(score)`.

```
    1   2   3   4   5 
a   3   0   0   0   0
b   0   2   0   0   0
c   0   0   0   4   0
```

I struggled to get this ? How can I get this result ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Your expected output is missing 3 score values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pivoting logic here:

```sql
SELECT
    people,
    COALESCE(SUM(score) FILTER (WHERE week = 1), 0) AS "1",
    COALESCE(SUM(score) FILTER (WHERE week = 2), 0) AS "2",
    COALESCE(SUM(score) FILTER (WHERE week = 3), 0) AS "3",
    COALESCE(SUM(score) FILTER (WHERE week = 4), 0) AS "4",
    COALESCE(SUM(score) FILTER (WHERE week = 5), 0) AS "5"
FROM table1
WHERE people IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY
    people
ORDER BY
    people;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: thank you for answer ! I wonder if the desired result is like week 1 to 4 ( only existing week), Are there another way to achieve this? 　I wonder whether there is a way to handle huge amount of week .. thank !

Comment: *"I wonder whether there is a way to handle huge amount of week(s)"* that's a different question, and I presume you also want the ability to just ask the query to change the column headings to suit as well. SQL can pivot data, but that does not mean it should. A large flexible pivot of data is something you should do in the **front-end** otherwise consider searching for "dynamic sql"

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL databases doesn't support pivot tables. [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67206824/15732755) is valid. However, I noticed that you have `postgresql` in your tags and postgresql support pivoting via the `tablefunc` extension. This how it's done in postgresql

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

SELECT 
    people, 
    COALESCE("1", 0),
    COALESCE("2", 0),
    COALESCE("3", 0),
    COALESCE("4", 0)
FROM CROSSTAB(
    $$
    SELECT people, week, sum(score) 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ORDER BY 1,2
    $$,
    $$
    SELECT DISTINCT(week) FROM table1
    $$
) AS ct(
    people VARCHAR,
    "1" INT,
    "2" INT,
    "3" INT,
    "4" INT
);
```

Please refer to [postgresql's documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html) section `F.41.1.4. crosstab(text, text)` for further information.